# Why does the redirect Uri need to be a non-existent site?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I was having a problem running the Windows version of a universal app.  I am trying to connect the app to facebook using OAuth.  On the Windows Phone side I can set my redirect Uri to something custom like http://facebook.com and it works fine - the result comes back with the correct values.  But when I try to use this in Windows Store side, it does not work.  Basically the result doesn't come back with the access token or anything else, and it looks like it returns the original start Uri instead.  furthermore it does not actually go to the sign in page, it skips over that part.

This Uri does not work in Windows Store (but it works in Windows Phone)
.

```
Uri endUri = new Uri("http://facebook.com", UriKind.Absolute);
```

This Uri works in Windows Store

```
var redirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();
Uri endUri = new Uri(redirectUri, UriKind.Absolute);
```

This is the code that is consuming the Uri.

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri, endUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
#endif

#if WINDOWS_APP
    WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, endUri);
    await ParseAuthenticationResult(result);
#endif
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: could you edit your question to make it clear which part of the code works and which doesn't? the code blocks and your comments are confusing.

Comment: - if you are already logged in, it will not go to the login page
- try using a non-existing url for the redirect url

Comment: @Jon I have not logged in yet in the Windows Store version of the app.  I will try the non existing Uri

Comment: @jon That is very strange I set my redirect Uri to var redirectUri = "http:// blsdkf093urlkwej0923upi3rj.sz"; and it works this time.  I still don't understand why though.